# positioning a div in the corner of an image

Tags: php, css, image, html, positioning

So I want to position my a meta-data div in the corner of every post image, but all the images are different sizes. How do I do this?

Heres an example of what I need:

[image]

This is the loop:

```
<div id="images">
    <?php wp_get_attachment_image(); ?>
</div>
<div id="date">
    <?php get_the_date(); ?>
</div>
```

I posted this @ wordpress.stackexchange but they said to post it here

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter what size the image is. You have to give the container div a `position:relative` and the corner div a `position:absolute` with `top:0` and `left:0`

HTML:

```
<div id="images"><?php wp_get_attachment_image(); ?>
<div id="date"><?php get_the_date(); ?></div>
</div>
```

*note date is inside the image tag!

CSS:

```
#images{
position:relative;
}

#date{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: all the images are text-align:center; with max-width:630px; so they sit in the middle of the screen

Comment: as long as the images are inside the div, it doesn't matter, as long as the divs have width and height. Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?